# Laravel-vue: show different icons with if / v-else

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I need to have three different icons based on the value of a db column "visibility".

Basically if:

value "1" -  only_me (must show an icon)

value "2" -  team_members (correctly show member avatars)

value "3" -  organization (must show another icon)

At the moment the value "2" works while for the value "1" and "3" it always shows the same icon as the value 1.

What am I doing wrong?
This is the code that is not working:

```
                                    <div class="mt-4 flex-shrink-0 flex items-center sm:mt-0" v-if="project.team_members.length && project.visibility === '2'">
                                        <div class="avatar-group">
                                            <img v-for="user in project.team_members" class="avatar avatar-xs" :src="user.avatar_url" :alt="user.name" :title="user.name"/>
                                        </div>   
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mt-4 flex-shrink-0 flex items-center sm:mt-0" v-if="project.visibility === '1'">
                                        <div class="avatar-group">
                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="#52525B" viewBox="0 0 256 256"><rect width="256" height="256" fill="none"></rect><rect x="40" y="88" width="176" height="128" rx="8" stroke-width="16" stroke="#52525B" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none"></rect><path d="M92,88V52a36,36,0,0,1,72,0V88" fill="none" stroke="#52525B" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="16"></path><circle cx="128" cy="152" r="12"></circle></svg>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mt-4 flex-shrink-0 flex items-center sm:mt-0" v-if="project.visibility === '3'">
                                        <div class="avatar-group">
                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="#52525B" viewBox="0 0 256 256"><rect width="256" height="256" fill="none"></rect><path d="M40,114.66667V56a8,8,0,0,1,8-8H208a8,8,0,0,1,8,8v58.66667c0,84.01533-71.306,111.85016-85.5438,116.57058a7.54755,7.54755,0,0,1-4.9124,0C111.306,226.51683,40,198.682,40,114.66667Z" fill="none" stroke="#52525B" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="16"></path><polyline points="202.402 172.082 128 120 53.597 172.082" fill="none" stroke="#52525B" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="16"></polyline></svg>                                            </div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: at the top of your html, put {{ project.team_members.length }} {{ project.visibility }} doing that you can debug properly your code. My guess is that visibility is a number, so when you're comparing with 3 egual signs the code fails

Comment: @SamuelAialaFerreira sorry, can you explain me better? I did not understand...

Comment: Is `project.visibility` stored as a numeric value or a string?

Comment: @Tyberio project.visibility is a numeric value "1", "2" or "3" in my table

Comment: @Tyberius do you have any ideas?